# Can Azure Event Grid give me FIFO behavior like this?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, messaging, azureservicebus, azure-eventgrid

Suppose I have events that propagate information like

```
       C
      /
A -- B
      \
       D
```

and suppose I need to guarantee a stagger like

```
                   C0 --------       
                   /
                  /
A0 -- B0 --------
                  \
                   D0 -----------------


                      ======== C1---------------    
       A1---==== B1 --
                      ================== D1----
```

(The `=` imply waiting)

Is this possible to do in out-of-box way with Event Grid?

Answer (score 3):

The Azure Event Grid is an event driven distributed Pub/Sub model for reliable delivery interested *discrete* events to the subscribers based on their subscriptions. It's not a data pipeline, and there is no guarantee in-order processing.

In the case of using an Azure Event Grid, I do recommend to push the discrete events to the *stream pipeline* (EventHub subscriber) and handling the business model in the stream analytics job such as ordering, etc.

Comment: Huge +1 for what @roman-kiss said. Right tool for the right job.